# How to extend/complete the dates in the Date column of a table? Using dplyr/sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have this data with missing dates in the Date column, how can I expand this column to the full range of dates since the start and end of each grouping?
The grouping are the columns Material and Category
[image]

How do you add the missing dates for each grouping of Material, Category from the first to the last date in each group?
Don't mind the Value column, I can fill those up with fill().

I tried to

```
group_by(Material,Category) %>% arrange(Date) %>% complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date),max(Date),by="days"))
```

But does not seems to work in SPARK.

Answer (score 0):

No experience with SPARK, but try this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
  arrange(Date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date),max(Date),by="days")) %>% 
  fill(Material, .direction = "down")
```

```
   Category       Date Material Value
1         A 2022-01-03     Iron    39
2         A 2022-01-04     Iron    45
3         A 2022-01-05     Iron    39
4         A 2022-01-06     Iron    39
5         A 2022-01-07     Iron    24
6         A 2022-01-08     Iron    NA
7         A 2022-01-09     Iron    NA
8         A 2022-01-10     Iron    35
9         A 2022-01-11     Iron    37
10        B 2022-02-03    Steel    45
11        B 2022-02-04    Steel    21
12        B 2022-02-05    Steel    NA
13        B 2022-02-06    Steel    NA
14        B 2022-02-07    Steel    34
15        B 2022-02-08    Steel    45
16        B 2022-02-09    Steel    NA
17        B 2022-02-10    Steel    NA
18        B 2022-02-11    Steel    67
19        C 2022-01-19   Copper    21
20        C 2022-01-20   Copper    NA
21        C 2022-01-21   Copper    NA
22        C 2022-01-22   Copper    NA
23        C 2022-01-23   Copper    NA
24        C 2022-01-24   Copper    33
25        C 2022-01-25   Copper    12
26        C 2022-01-26   Copper    NA
27        C 2022-01-27   Copper    NA
28        C 2022-01-28   Copper    NA
29        C 2022-01-29   Copper    NA
30        C 2022-01-30   Copper    NA
31        C 2022-01-31   Copper    NA
32        C 2022-02-01   Copper    NA
33        C 2022-02-02   Copper    NA
34        C 2022-02-03   Copper    NA
35        C 2022-02-04   Copper    NA
36        C 2022-02-05   Copper    NA
37        C 2022-02-06   Copper    NA
38        C 2022-02-07   Copper    NA
39        C 2022-02-08   Copper    NA
40        C 2022-02-09   Copper    NA
41        C 2022-02-10   Copper    NA
42        C 2022-02-11   Copper    NA
43        C 2022-02-12   Copper    NA
44        C 2022-02-13   Copper    NA
45        C 2022-02-14   Copper    NA
46        C 2022-02-15   Copper    NA
47        C 2022-02-16   Copper    NA
48        C 2022-02-17   Copper    NA
49        C 2022-02-18   Copper    NA
50        C 2022-02-19   Copper    NA
51        C 2022-02-20   Copper    NA
52        C 2022-02-21   Copper    NA
53        C 2022-02-22   Copper    NA
54        C 2022-02-23   Copper    NA
55        C 2022-02-24   Copper    NA
56        C 2022-02-25   Copper    NA
57        C 2022-02-26   Copper    NA
58        C 2022-02-27   Copper    NA
59        C 2022-02-28   Copper    90
60        C 2022-03-01   Copper    NA
61        C 2022-03-02   Copper    NA
62        C 2022-03-03   Copper    80
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. Do you know why this could be happening? Error in complete(., Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "days")): unused argument (Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "days"))